# cakePHP3のローカル環境インストールについて

Tags: cakephp, cygwin, xampp

Windows8環境ローカルPC上に、XAMPPとCygWinをインストールし、cakePHP3の実装チャレンジをしています。
cakePHP3のインストールまでは成功したのですが、bakeしようとすると、以下のエラーが出て先に進みません。

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/cygdrive/c/httpd/cakePHP/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php, line 48]
```

問題解決出来ないか色々調べてみたのですが、解消出来ませんでした。
[こちらの記事](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941506/sqlstate-hy000-2002-while-running-bake-command)で同じ症状の方がいらっしゃったようなのですが、書き方が間違っているのか、PATHの書き方がよくわからず、対処出来ませんでした。
どなたかアドバイスいただく事は出来ませんでしょうか？

Comment: そのエラーはソケット経由でDBに接続できないときにでるエラーだったかと思います。Datasourceの設定を見直してみてください。

Comment: また、php.ini の `pdo_mysql.default_socket` の値も確認してみてください。

Comment: @nojimage
回答ありがとうございました！
色々設定見直してみたりしているのですが、なかなか直らず、まだ解決していません。
でもその辺りと言う事ですので、暫くじっくり見直してみる事にします。
解決するまでお返事無しもどうかと思いましたので、まず先に感謝を。ありがとうございます！